# Join with Entity Framework and F#

Tags: entity-framework, linq, f#, anonymous-types, c#-to-f#

What seems to be an easy task in C# doesn't seem so easy in F#...

Given the following types in C# I want to make an inner join with F#:

```cs
public partial class Foo
{
    public long FooID { get; set; }
    public long BarID { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Bar
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeColumn1 { get; set; }
    public bool SomeColumn2 { get; set; }
}
```

So my try at doing this is:

```
let dbContext = DatabaseManager.Instance.ProduceContext()

let barIdForeignKey(f: Foo) =
    f.BarID

let barIdPrimaryKey(b: Bar) =
    b.ID

let joinResult(f: Foo, b: Bar) =
    (f, b)

let joinedElements =
    dbContext.foos.Join(dbContext.bars, barIdForeignKey, barIdPrimaryKey, joinResult)
```

But the compiler complains with something like:

> Possible overload: (extension)
>
> ```
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.Join<'TOuter, 'TInner, 'TKey, 'TResult>(
>     inner:            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'TInner>,
>     outerKeySelector: System.Func<'TOuter, 'TKey>,
>     innerKeySelector: System.Func<'TInner, 'TKey>,
>     resultSelector:   System.Func<'TOuter, 'TInner, 'TResult>)
>   : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'TResult>
> ```
>
> Type constraint mismatch. The type `'d * 'e -> foo * bar` is not compatible with type `System.Func<'a, 'b, 'c>`
>
> The type `'d * 'e -> foo * bar` is not compatible with the type `System.Func<'a, 'b, 'c>`

Not sure how to read this. Maybe it's that I cannot return a tuple at the end? In C# I would need an anonymous type, like `new { Foo = foo, Bar = bar }`, not sure how to do that in F#.

Comment: Why not use a [query expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions)? In any case, try changing `let joinResult(f: Foo, b: Bar) =` to `let joinResult (f: Foo) (b: Bar) =`.

Comment: Joins are a *very* strong smell when using ORMs. They mean that the mapping is wrong and some important relations are missing. If `Foo` had a `Bar` property, you wouldn't need to join. EF would generate the proper SQL to load the related entities. You can control whether the related entities are loaded eagerly or lazily.

Comment: F# will often automatically convert F# functions to .NET delegate types (e.g. `Func<_,_,_>`) at method invocations, but you need to use curried rather than tupled inputs (e.g. `let joinResult (f:Foo) (b:Bar) = ...`).

Comment: Signature `'d * 'e -> foo * bar` reads like `Func<Tuple<'d, 'e>, Tuple<foo, bar>>`, hence the incompatibility with `Func<'a, 'b, 'c>`

Comment: @ildjarn thanks I'll try query expressions next, but your suggestion about using currified arguments works (which is weird because currification arguments is an F# feature, so I was expecting EntityFramework to not accept them). You might want (or @kvb) to put that as an answer so I can upvote accordingly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the advice, it's quite possible that the mapping is right but I'm not using the correct querying approach, I'll look into that.

Comment: @knocte : I didn't answer because I was expecting this to be closed as a duplicate by now. ;-] I'll try to find one shortly.

Comment: I had already looked for one before posting here... and in fact now if I google for "join" "F#" "EntityFramework" my question comes as first result ;)

Comment: @knocte : Your problem has nothing to do with EF, though; it's to do with the way the compiler marshals F# functions into .NET delegates.

Comment: sure, but many people may face it when dealing with C#-generated entities for EntityFramework, so I think it's good to mention/tag it

Comment: So, implement all easy tasks in C# (and doesn't seem so easy in F#), and reference it in F#. In this way it will be easy in F# :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution (thanks @ildjarn) using currified arguments for the last func:

```
let dbContext = DatabaseManager.Instance.ProduceContext()

let barIdForeignKey(f: Foo) =
    f.BarID

let barIdPrimaryKey(b: Bar) =
    b.ID

let joinResult(f: Foo) (b: Bar) =
    (f, b)

let joinedElements =
    dbContext.foos.Join(dbContext.bars, barIdForeignKey, barIdPrimaryKey, joinResult)
```

Which in the end can be simplified to:

```
let joinedElements =
    dbContext.foos.Join (dbContext.bars,
                         (fun f -> f.barID),
                         (fun b -> b.ID),
                         (fun f b -> (f,b))
                        )
```

@PanagiotisKanavos also gave me a hint about joins using an ORM being a code-smell, and that let me discover that there was actually a `Bar` property in the `Foo` class (so that I don't need to fiddle with BarID column, as this Bar property is populated under the hood by EntityFramework this way anyway). This, combined with @ildjarn's original suggestion for using [query expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions), led me to the best answer:

```
let dbContext = DatabaseManager.Instance.ProduceContext()

let joinedElements =
    query {
        for foo in dbContext.foos do
            select (foo.Bar, foo.SomeColumn1)
    }
```